# C# send byte[] as JSON to WCF Rest endpoint. 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, arrays, json, httpwebrequest

I saw below but it adds overhead of encode and decode strings.

[C# - Send byte[] as part of json object using HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138779/c-sharp-send-byte-as-part-of-json-object-using-httpwebrequest)

I have a request object like below

```
[DataContract]
public class MyRequest
{
 [DataMember]
 public byte[] SampleByteArray { get; set; }

 [DataMember]
 public string UserId { get; set; }

}
```

I have below method that returns a byte[]

```
public byte[] SerializeToByteArray<T>(T input)
{
  byte[] byteArray = null;
  BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    bf.Serialize(ms, input);
    byteArray = ms.ToArray();
  }
  return byteArray;
}
```

I am creating my request object like below

```
MyRequest myRequest = new MyRequest();
myRequest.SampleByteArray = SerializeToByteArray(myDTO);
myRequest.UserId = "XXX";
```

I am making my HttpWebRequest object like below

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.KeepAlive = false;

//100,000 milliseconds (100 seconds) need 10 minutes 
request.Timeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalMilliseconds;
string stringfydata = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myRequest);
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringfydata);
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
requestStream.Close();
```

I am making WCF Rest call like below

```
string responseData;
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
   using (var respStream = response.GetResponseStream())
   {
      using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(respStream)
      {
          responseData = reader.ReadToEnd();
      }
   }
}
```

I am getting 400 Bad Request exception at

```
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse()
```

To test I changed my code like below and now atleast my service code gets hit and I am getting valid nice exception message which shows that my service is working.

```
MyRequest myRequest = new MyRequest();
myRequest.SampleByteArray = null;
myRequest.UserId = "XXX";
```

It looks like I am having issue sending byte[] to my service.

Can anyone please tell me how to send a byte[] as a property in a object that is converted into JSON format and calls a WCF Rest endpoint.

Please see below my service briefly.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyInterface
{
  [Description("My test method")]
  [OperationContract]
  [WebInvoke(
    UriTemplate = "mymethod",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
   )]
  ServiceResponse GetResponse(MyRequest request);
}

public class MyInterface : IMyInterface
{
 public ServiceResponse GetResponse(MyRequest request)
 {
  .... code goes here
 }
}
```